# How to set max value in ZedGraph (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, zedgraph

When I get one value on Y Axis, it shows four "1". How can I set the maximum value by default?

Comment: thanks for attention, I found that I need: `myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max`

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth: Sorry, I can't accept it, because when I try to do it, the following message pops up: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Comment: ok. Thanks anyway for posting it as an answer, so everybody can see from the overview, that it already has been answered :-)

Answer (score 0):

it turned out, that I need to set: `myPane.YAxis.Scale.Max`